# Submitting Firebase Credentials to App Store reviewer for Reviews to test Push Notifcations

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store, apple-push-notifications, appstore-approval

Our app uses Firebase's console to send out push notifications to our users manually based on a topic they subscribe to. I've just submitted the app for beta test review a few minutes ago and then wondered if I should also give them our firebase credentials so they can login, fire a sample notification and see the resulting view controller from where users can share the push notifications content onto social media.

I asked because access to the firebase console(or a way to send notifications) they wont be able to test out the entire app(they technically wont be able to see just one VC.).

Is it safe to share Firebase credentials with the App Review team? How can i avoid rejection(if they choose to reject me) because of this.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Apple says on [Common App Rejections](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/):

> **Incomplete Information**: Enter all of the details needed to review your
>   app in the App Review Information section of iTunes Connect. If some
>   features require signing in, provide a valid demo account username and
>   password. If there are special configurations to set, include the
>   specifics. If features require an environment that is hard to
>   replicate or require specific hardware, be prepared to provide a demo
>   video or the hardware. Also, please make sure your contact information
>   is complete and up-to-date.

In other words, there is an additional information field in iTunes Connect. Use it for info needed to test the app. Given this happens on a regular basis, one can presume it is safe.

Without knowing your exact situation, I do not know whether you should include it. Just look over the quote above - perhaps a demo video would be better?